# Is NATing possible in case of IPV6 addressing mode anyway?

Tags: nat, ipv6

**Setup:**

A(2001::1:123) <------> **B**(2001::1:124) <------> C(2001::1:125)

where A,B and C are the systems.And apply rule of NAT(SNAT/DNAT) on system B for forwarding a packets from C to B,B to C,A to B and B to  .

Is this possible to NAT in case of IPV6 anyway?

Comment: I could answer this in three characters but the system requires me to say more than yes.  Look at [netfilter6](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch18s04.html) if using linux

Comment: I have try this but still it is not working. I could  apply some command as below.

Comment: Sadly, we cannot just give you an answer, and it sounds like this is a linux question anyway which is off-topic.

Comment: I have try this but still it is not working. I could  apply some command as below. ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -w -s 2001::1:123 --sport 8000 -d 2001::1:125 -j SNAT --to-source 2001:1:124:9001 and ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -w -s 2001::1:123 --sport 8000 -d 2001::1:124 -j DNAT --to-source 2001:1:125:9000

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 doesn't oficially have NAT. There is the *EXPERIMENTAL* [*RFC 6296, IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Prefix Translation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6296), but it is not the NAPT that most people assume. It is a one-to-one NAT.

There are some real problems with trying to use NAT on IPv6, and some are listed in the RFC.

NAT is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4 until IPv6 can become ubiquitous. NAT breaks the IP end-to-end paradigm, but there are not nearly enough IPv4 addresses for that. IPv6 give you an almost unlimited number of addresses in order to restore the IP end-to-end paradigm, where every host has a unique IP address.

Some network devices, and some host OSes have NAT for IPv6, but read the RFC to understand the problems this can cause.

Comment: fwiw he is not asking about natpt

Comment: @MikePennington, I wasn't suggesting that, only that is what most people think of with NAT, and that even the experimental NPTv6 doesn't have that (explicitly forbids it). NPTv6 may, or may not, work for what is asked, depending on what may break, much of which is listed in the RFC.